# Where are Yesod binaries to work with in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, haskell, yesod

I followed [this](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) quickstart tutorial.

After installing the *yesod-platform*, I try to run the *yesod* command with no success.

Am I doing something wrong?

I know how to fix it ---adding the right path to $PATH. The problem is, I just don't know which path should I add.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that adding `/Library/Haskell/bin/` to your $PATH variable works fine.

Comment: I had some missing symlinks or something and ended up finding it under `~/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/yesod-bin-1.2.2.1/bin/yesod`

Answer (score 0):

For me, `yesod` ended up in `~/.cabal/bin`